# How to restrict deleting specified items from listbox using access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a listbox that contains 18 items. The selected item can be deleted from the listbox by clicking a 'Delete' button. How can I prevent a user from  deleting certain items that I specify?

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    Dim i As Integer

    With Me.listbox1
        For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .Selected(i) = True Then
                .RemoveItem i
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Which specific items don't you want deleted? Certain position in the list, or certain Text content ?  Either way, you can check in your loop and not delete if it's one of the "required" items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the values in a table? Then you could have a column in the table which specified whether the field could be deleted or not, which would be easy to build into your VBA.

**Edit for further explanation:**

Have you listbox be unbound (i.e. no specific field as its datasource).

Create a table which contains columns for an ID (as an autonumber), the values you want to appear in your listbox (as a textbox), and a final column you can tick yes or no on (as a boolean or yes/no field). E.g.

```
ID     Values                Allow deletion?
1      Example               Yes
2      Another example       No
3      Yes another example   Yes
```

In your listbox's rowsource, select that table.

Your delete sub could now run the following code.

```
dim qry as string
dim strLookup as string

strLookup = dlookup("[Allow deletion]","[Your Table]", YOURSELECTEDFIELDHERE & "=[Values]")

if strLookup = "No" Then
    msgbox "You're not allowed to delete this field."
    exit sub
else 
    qry = "DELETE * FROM [Your Table] WHERE [Values] = YOURSELECTEDFIELDHERE"
    CurrentDB.Execute qry
    Me.YourListBoxName.Requery
end if
```

This will look for the value you've grabbed from your listbox, match it against the Allow deletions field, delete it if that field is marked as Yes or leave it be if it's marked as No.

If you want to only temporarily delete the field and have it appear next time you load the form - in effect, hide it, you'd have to add a further column to the table called "Show", which would also be a Yes/No field, and set the default to Yes.

You'd then set your rowsource to `SELECT * FROM [YOURTABLE] WHERE [Show] = "Yes"`.

Then `qry` in the above code should instead be set to:

```
UPDATE [YOURTABLE] SET [YOURTABLE].[Show] = "No" WHERE ((([YOURTABLE].[Values])=YOURSELECTEDFIELD));
```

This will then change the value of Show to No, so when the listbox is requeried, it'll no longer appear.

You'll need to run another query to change all of them back to Yes on the form exit.

Comment: I'm new to vba, could you please give the logic.

Comment: You are awesome.Thank you so much. One question. If i delete the item which is Allow deletion 'Yes', then again when i reload that list every time in the form load ,are the itmes deleted previously will they show in the listbox?

Comment: No, because they'll also be deleted at table level, which is where your listbox will be getting its rows from. If you want to only temporarily delete them (in effect, hide them), add another column to the table which is SHOW as a Yes/No. You can then change the SQL statement to change Show to No rather than delete it, and have your row source work that in as a condition - e.g. row source would be SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE SHOW=YES.

Comment: Rather Allow deletion column do i need to add SHOW column. Where should i change in the above code. please help.